# scalajs removeEventListener not working if using a scala function

Tags: scala.js

This code does not work as expected (the `keydown` function still is executed when pressing a key):

```
import org.scalajs.dom.raw.Event
import org.scalajs.dom.{console, document}
import scala.scalajs.js

def keydown(e: Event) { console.log(e) }
document.addEventListener("keydown", keydown)
document.removeEventListener("keydown", keydown)
```

This modified code does indeed work as expected:

```
def keydown_(e: Event) { console.log(e) }
val keydown: js.Function1[Event, Unit] = (e: Event) => keydown_ _
document.addEventListener("keydown", keydown)
document.removeEventListener("keydown", keydown)
```

Why is so?
And is it possible to remove this extra boilerplate line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala Functions and JS Functions are different types, you need to convert from one to another. This is done for you implicitly, but this conversion creates a new instance of JS Function every time the conversion is called.

So calling the conversion multiple times, even if implicitly, you will get a different instance of JS Function every time. Even though those instances wrap the same Scala function, the browser doesn't know that. In order to `removeEventListener`, you need to provide it with the exact same JS Function reference that you passed to `addEventListener`, which is why your `val` example works but `def` doesn't.

Comment: ok, thanks. so what is the more compact approach to achieve this?
I am currently using this:
`val keydown: js.Function1[Event, Unit] = (e: Event) => { console.log(e) }`

but it looks ugly, compared to the more compact (not-working) form `def keydown(e: Event) { console.log(e) }`.

Comment: @DavidPortabella You could create a wrapper like `case class Callback[Ev](fn: js.Function1[Ev, Unit])` to help with type inference, and use it like `val cb = Callback[Event](ev => console.log(ev))`, and just refer to `cb.fn` when you need the JS function. You might need to tweak that code slightly to get desired type inference, I haven't run it.
You could also use one of the ScalaJS DOM libraries to handle these things for you.

Comment: The code above already uses https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom library. Do you mean another scalajs DOM library? which one? I did not find any other one (that can handle this).

Comment: @DavidPortabella scala-js-dom is just a facade for the browser DOM, it has to mirror the native low level DOM API. I meant higher level reactive UI libraries like https://slinky.dev, https://outwatch.github.io, or my own https://github.com/raquo/Laminar – with such libraries you typically don't need to imperatively micromanage event handlers – they offer different, more declarative abstractions. If you're new to this whole area, consider also checking out React.js documentation as a starter – it's not Scala, but they have lots of good docs covering modern UI development methods.